# GPS convert meters to degree of displacement

Tags: c++, gps, geo, boost-geometry, marble

I need to draw a geo-projected circle on the map. e.g. I want the center to be defined in terms of latitude and longitude and its radius to be defined in meters. I am using [`KDE Marble`](https://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/index.html). In the API there is a function [`drawEllipse`](https://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/classMarble_1_1GeoPainter.html#a8c0d95d021a9c2774043435b6dc87269) that takes a center as (lat, lon) and width and height of the ellipse.

```
GeoPainter::drawEllipse(const GeoDataCoordinates& center, qreal width, qreal height, bool isGeoProjected = false)
```

For a geo projected ellipse the width and height are considered to be in degrees. However I need them to be in meters. There is no simple conversion between degrees and meters because it depends on the position of the center in globe.

I need to convert the radius of the circle (in meters) to a pair of degree of displacement of a vector pointing to the center from the center of the earth.

I am also using boost geometry to do other geometrical calculation. Is there any function in `boost-geometry` that performs this conversion ?

### UPDATE I

I first tried to have two GeoDataCoordinates one is the center and the other is on the perimeter. I expected that the difference between their latitudes and longitudes will work with the `drawEllipse` function.

```
painter->drawEllipse(_center, std::abs(_border.longitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree)-_center.longitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree)), std::abs(_border.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree)-_center.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree)), true);
```

However it produces an ellipse way smaller that I expected. The border point which was supposed to be on the circumference is beyond the ellipse.
[image]

### UPDATE II

Then I tried to use the central angle formula on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

```
double angular_distance = acos(
     (sin(_center.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Radian))*sin(_border.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Radian)))
    +(cos(_center.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Radian))*cos(_border.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Radian)))
    *(double)cos(std::abs(_border.longitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Radian)-_center.longitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Radian)))
);
painter->drawEllipse(_center, stmr::internal::rad2deg(angular_distance), stmr::internal::rad2deg(angular_distance), true);
```

[image]

The results are not much different from the previous one. However this time the ellipse is slightly larger than the previous one.

### UPDATE III

The distance ratio between the arc and the sphere's great circle circumference is used to calculate the angular displacement in @ttemple's answer

```
painter->drawEllipse(_center, 2*(distance/earthRadiusKm)* 180.0/3.14159, 2*(distance/earthRadiusKm)* 180.0/3.14159, true);
```

produces a correct ellipse.

[image]

So I multiplied the angles with `2.0` with **UPDATE II** code and that also produced the similar (like **UPDATE III**) result.

### UPDATE IV

But the problem with `drawEllipse` is that it actually draws a polygon with much fewer points on a zoomed out state. Sometimes it looks like a Square.

[image]

So it is a better option to draw more points on the ellipse circumference so that the fence looks like a circle in a zoomed out view too. The [KDE Forum Link](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=111670) posted in the comments does the same.

```
GeoDataLineString ellipse;
qreal lon = 0.0;
qreal lat = 0.0;
int precision = 180;
for ( int i = 0; i < precision; ++i){
    qreal t = 1.0 - 2.0 * (qreal)(i) / (qreal)(precision);
    lat = center.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree)  + 0.5 * radius * sqrt(1.0 - t * t);
    lon = center.longitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree) + 0.5 * radius * t;
    ellipse << GeoDataCoordinates(lon, lat, 0.0, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree);
}
for ( int i = 0; i < precision; ++i){
    qreal t = 2.0 * (qreal)(i) / (qreal)(precision) - 1.0;
    lat = center.latitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree)  - 0.5 * radius * sqrt(1.0 - t * t);
    lon = center.longitude(GeoDataCoordinates::Degree) + 0.5 * radius * t;
    ellipse << GeoDataCoordinates(lon, lat, 0.0, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree);
}
painter->drawPolyline(ellipse);
```

However it draws a circle with much higher radius than the input. I think the snippet posted there is incomplete. There are unused conditional blocks that I ignored in my code. Also the code specifically mentions in comments that the radius of the fence has to be given in km. I did so. Also I didn't understand that math behind this. It doesn't use Earth Radius anywhere in the snippet. May be a minor correction to this code will produce a better ellipse. The math looks like some parametric curve which produces half of the ellipse. But there is no reference to the equation.

[image]

Also this works only in first quadrant where both lat and lon is positive

Comment: Did you try this example from KDE forum? 
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=111670

Comment: The NISTunits package may help, I’ve used it previously for unit conversions https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NISTunits/index.html.

Comment: Should the circle be on the surface of the sphere, or projected above the sphere? (if that makes sense)

Comment: Projected on the surface. I am actually drawing a geofence.

Comment: Thanks for the KDE Forum Link. Not yet tried. Will check.

Comment: Is the distance in meters a circular distance, or a chordal distance? (circular meaning measured along the surface of the globe, along the curvature.)

Comment: It is circular, measured along the globe surface.

Comment: Have a look at the PROJ.4-based projections and transformations facilities: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/boost/geometry/srs/ and specifically  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/boost/geometry/srs/transformation.hpp Those are not documented in very details yet, but you may find your way. There should be some examples in the Geometry codebase.

Comment: Please check edit

Answer (score 0):

The radius of the fence, as measured along the curve of the sphere, divided by the radius of the sphere is the angle in radians.

```
double circular_radius_of_fence = 1000;    // circular radius of fence
double sphere_radius = 6378000;   // radius of sphere, meters

// included angle in radians
double ang_radians = circular_radius_of_fence / sphere_radius;

// convert to degrees
double ang_degrees = ang_radians * 180.0/PI;

// width and height of circle is twice the angle
double width = ang_degrees * 2;
double height = ang_degrees * 2;
```

Comment: Please check Edit

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the [KDE Forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=111670) actually the implementation in [`GeoPainter::drawEllipse`](https://api.kde.org/stable/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/GeoPainter_8cpp_source.html#l00289).

```
const int precision = qMin<qreal>( width / degreeResolution / 8 + 1, 81 )
```

This line in that implementation reduces the precision such that it looks like a square, when zoomed out. So I copied the drawEllipse code with single line modification for higher precision.

```
void FenceLayer::drawFence(Marble::GeoPainter* painter, Marble::GeoDataCoordinates center, double radius){
    double height = radius;
    double width  = radius;
    // Initialize variables
    const qreal centerLon = center.longitude( GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    const qreal centerLat = center.latitude( GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    const qreal altitude = center.altitude();

    // Ensure a valid latitude range: 
    if ( centerLat + 0.5 * height > 90.0 || centerLat - 0.5 * height < -90.0 ) {
        return;
    }

    // Don't show the ellipse if it's too small:
    GeoDataLatLonBox ellipseBox( centerLat + 0.5 * height, centerLat - 0.5 * height,
                            centerLon + 0.5 * width,  centerLon - 0.5 * width, 
                            GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    if ( !_map->viewport()->viewLatLonAltBox().intersects( ellipseBox ) ||
    !_map->viewport()->resolves( ellipseBox ) ) return;

    GeoDataLinearRing ellipse;

    // Optimizing the precision by determining the size which the 
    // ellipse covers on the screen:
    const qreal degreeResolution = _map->viewport()->angularResolution() * RAD2DEG;
    // To create a circle shape even for very small precision we require uneven numbers:
    const int scaled_resolution = qMin<qreal>( width / degreeResolution / 8 + 1, 81 );
    const int precision = qMin<qreal>( width / degreeResolution / 8 + 1, 81 ) < 81 ? 81 : scaled_resolution ;

    // Calculate the shape of the upper half of the ellipse:
    for ( int i = 0; i <= precision; ++i ) {
        const qreal t = 1.0 - 2.0 * (qreal)(i) / (qreal)(precision);
        const qreal lat = centerLat + 0.5 * height * sqrt( 1.0 - t * t );
        const qreal lon = centerLon + 0.5 * width * t;
        ellipse << GeoDataCoordinates( lon, lat, altitude, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    }
    // Calculate the shape of the lower half of the ellipse:
    for ( int i = 0; i <= precision; ++i ) {
        const qreal t = 2.0 * (qreal)(i) / (qreal)(precision) -  1.0;
        const qreal lat = centerLat - 0.5 * height * sqrt( 1.0 - t * t );
        const qreal lon = centerLon + 0.5 * width * t;
        ellipse << GeoDataCoordinates( lon, lat, altitude, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    }

    painter->drawPolygon(ellipse);
}
```

While calling `drawFence` I convert distance to degree of displacement as suggested in @ttemple's answer.

```
drawFence(painter, _center, 2*(distance/earthRadiusKm)* 180.0/3.14159);
```

Where `distance` is the radius of the fence.